# Python 3: How to create a list to print its every element on a new line - without loops or sep = "\n"

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Let's say I have a list 'mylist'. For example, I prepared it like this:

```
mylist = ['AB', 'CD', 'EF']
```

I need to print out each element of 'mylist' on a new line.
However, I am not allowed to use loops (as in 'for i in mylist...') and I can't say:

```
print(*mylist, sep = "\n")
```

Although the last command gives exactly the output I need.

No, I have to somehow create/prepare 'mylist' in such a way that the desired print output is achieved based on the following command:

```
print(mylist)
```

Is it even possible?
Notice, it's not a duplicate post - it's more about how to format the list to begin with, not about printing per se.

Comment: I get the feeling that this is an exercise that teaches you that you can redefine already existing functions.

Answer (score 3):

Really simple:

```
print ("\n".join(mylist))
```

The method `str.join` uses the string to join an iterable.

Comment: This answer does not satisfy the conditions of the question asked.

Comment: in what way does it not satisfy the condition?

Comment: `I need to print out each element of 'mylist' on a new line. However, I am not allowed to use loops (as in 'for i in mylist...') and I can't say:` <--- does exactly that.-

Comment: My question states: "No, I have to somehow create/prepare 'mylist' in such a way that the desired print output is achieved based on the following command: print(mylist)"

Comment: then do something simple as `mylist="\n".join(mylist)`. We can't teach you basic python if you ask about list handling...

Answer (score 1):

The standard `list` type has a number of built-in behaviors, including a representation with brackets around the list and commas between (`repr`s of) the items. There's no way to get the behavior you desire, from the statement you specify (`print(mylist)`), *and* use the standard `list` type.

You may define a class `MyList` whose `__str__()` method generates the desired format:

```
class MyList(list):
    def __str__(self):
       return "\n".join(self)

mylist = MyList(['AB', 'CD', 'EF'])

print(mylist)
```

Or you may redefine `print()`:

```
def print(*args, print=print, **kwargs):
    if type(args[0]) is list and len(args) == 1:
        args = ["\n".join(args[0])]
    print(*args, **kwargs)
```

Either way is just hiding the code away somewhere else in order to stick to some arbitrary rule about what you're allowed to write. If you're going to do that, in a class is probably the more acceptable spot to put it.

Answer (score -3):

You can print each element separated too on a new line such as:

```
print(mylist[0]), print(mylist[1])
```

Comment: No, as I stated in my question, it has to print as desired based JUST on: print(mylist)

Comment: No, you did *not* state your question like that. You said you needed to preformat your list. And that's a flexible term.

Answer (score -8):

I found the solution.

'mylist' shouldn't be a list, it should be created as a string like this - then it prints as desired:

```
mylist = 'AB\nCD\nEF'
print(mylist)
```

Comment: That does not fulfill the conditions of your own question, because your question was about printing the list.

Comment: Also, you were not allowed to use `'\n'` as a separation, right?